# Como solucionar margen de flipcard con css y html

Tags: html, css, css3

Hola buenas tengo este flipcard que he creado pero se me ve pegado al margen de abajo y no puedo añadirle margen para dejar el espacio del final de la página.

```css
.flipscards__1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px groove;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.flipscards__1:hover {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    transition: transform 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipscards__1">
            <h3>Productos</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis magnam possimus itaque non maiores natus ut deleniti labore recusandae velit, cumque doloremque suscipit quidem, totam temporibus asperiores similique? Voluptatibus, harum?</p>
            <a href="">Leer Más</a>
        </div>
```

Pero cuando le pongo un margin-bottom por ejemplo de 20px no se añade el margen y se queda pegado al final de la página, como podría solucionarlo?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas objetos en posición absolute, no se usa margin pues la posición de estos objetos son absolutos, por lo que se usa las instrucciones, top, left, right o bottom, sin el margin para mover el objeto, por ejemplo:

```css
.flipscards__1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px groove;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/* Propiedad Bottom */
.flipscards__1 {
  bottom: 30px;
}

.flipscards__1:hover {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    transition: transform 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipscards__1">
            <h3>Productos</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis magnam possimus itaque non maiores natus ut deleniti labore recusandae velit, cumque doloremque suscipit quidem, totam temporibus asperiores similique? Voluptatibus, harum?</p>
            <a href="">Leer Más</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Funcionó muchas gracias...